# Where are professionals? The following code does not work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, node.js, reactjs

The alert is not shown on iOS after this line in the following code 
    let outputAudioBuffer = await window[transformName+"Transform"](globalAudioBuffer, ...transformArgs); 
This means that this line in the following code is not understood on iOS. How to solve this problem, please?

```js
async function createAudio(blob) {
    var fawzy = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     arrayBuffer = await (await fetch(fawzy)).arrayBuffer();
}

async function loadTransform(e, transformName, ...transformArgs) {

    let outputSection = document.getElementById("output");
    outputSection.style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("body").style.overflow = "hidden";

    if(!globalAudioBuffer) {
        let ctx = new AudioContext();
     await ctx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function (buffer) {
  globalAudioBuffer = buffer;
 });
} 

    let outputAudioBuffer = await window[transformName+"Transform"](globalAudioBuffer, ...transformArgs);
    alert("Working"); // The alert is not shown on iOS. 
    let outputWavBlob = await audioBufferToWaveBlob(outputAudioBuffer);
    let audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(outputWavBlob); 
    let audioTag = document.getElementById("audioTag");
    audioTag.src = audioUrl;
    audioTag.addEventListener('click', audioTag.play());
    blob = outputWavBlob;
}
```

Comment: try printing `transformName` / `window[transformName+"Transform"]` / `globalAudioBuffer` / `transformArgs`, break it down to little bits and pieces and see which part went wrong

Comment: when i delete **await**, the following alert  works, but the createObjectURL function receive a non blob argument what should i use instead of **await** @Neverever

Comment: can i use promise instead of **await** @Neverever

Comment: I'm only taking a wild guess here, it sounds like `await window[]` is hanging, you need to trace what it is doing.

Comment: *can i use promise instead of await*, it's not a valid question, **await** is one of the ways to retrieve result from a `Promise`, the other way is using the **callback**